# Python interpretor repeat command

Tags: python, repeat

In the Python interpretor to repeat the last command just press up arrow.
Often I might be testing a code segment which involves several lines - for exzmple two nested for loops. i often make typo and want to change the body of the loops and repeat the code block of the two for loops without typing in the whole lot again.

Is there a way to do that?

I know some of you will say to put in in a file and execute the file but sometimes it would be good to be able to repeat code blocks in the interpretor.

Comment: why not add this code to a function and then call it?

Comment: You might find a shell like DreamPie does what you want - http://www.dreampie.org/download.html

Comment: I heard good things about IPython. I think it has much better history editing.

Answer (score 0):

iPython does this very well, and provides many rich mechanisms for editing post-facto etc. See `%macro` here: http://pages.physics.cornell.edu/~myers/teaching/ComputationalMethods/python/ipython.html